# Rails is not connecting to remote mongo db through SSH tunnelling

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I have my mongoid.yml file set up like (eventually production environment will be called staging):

```
development:
  host: staging.domain.com
  port: 27018
  username: domain
  password: passw0rd
  database: domain_production

production:
  host: localhost
  port: 27017
  username: domain
  password: passw0rd
  database: domain_production
```

I can open up my tunneling like:

```
ssh deployer@staging.domain.com -L 27018:staging.domain.com:27017
```

I can open up my mongo shell with

```
mongo --port 27018
```

I can run mongod on the remote port but again, none of the entries on the staging server show up.  (Do I need to run mongod?)

But when I go to the domain_production I don't see the documents that show up on the website itself.  And when I try to start the rails server it hangs.  Am I missing a step?

Comment: Are you in production mode or development mode? Most likely you are doing this for development, and you have your development and production configuration reversed.

Answer (score 0):

mongod is the mongo database process. It needs be run prior to running the "mongo" shell. mongo is the interactive javascript shell that you use to interact with the mongod process.

mongod picks up the configuration file, and starts listening on port 21017 by default. 21017 + 1000 = 22017 is the port where the http interface shows up.  Did i answer your question?